# ZF2 Call to undefined method Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http::setInputFilter()

Tags: forms, zend-framework2, runtime-error, file-transfer

Created a form and added an fields to upload an image to a folder on server I Have checked by print the value after submit the form all the values are working fine it gives the above mentioned error and not save the data to DB:

My controller:

```
public function vouchersAction()

 {
      $vouchers = new VouchersForm();
      $vouchers->get('submit')->setValue('Vouchers');

      $request = $this->getRequest();

     if ($request->isPost()) {
         //echo '<pre>'; print_r($request);
            //exit();
         $vouchers = new Vouchers();
         $vouchers = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();  
         $vouchers->setDestination('C:\xampp\htdocs\reisesparer\public\images\coupons');
         $vouchers->setInputFilter($vouchers->getInputFilter());
         $vouchers->setData($request->getPost());
         if ($vouchers->receive()) { 
            echo "The file has been uploaded!";
             }
         if ($vouchers->isValid()) {
             $vouchers->exchangeArray($vouchers->getData());
             $this->getVouchersTable()->saveVouchers($vouchers);


             return $this->redirect()->toRoute('vouchers');
         }
     }
     return array('vouchers' => $vouchers);
 }
```

Error:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http::setInputFilter()`

Answer (score 0):

Your action does not make any sense right now.
1. You init `VouchersForm()` class to `$vouchers`
2. If request is `POST` then you do:

```
 $vouchers = new Vouchers();
 $vouchers = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
```

You override class from point `#1` (`VouchersForm`) with new class `Vouchers`.
You do nothing with it, then you override `Vouchers` class with `Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http()` and you try to call methods from class `VouchersForm` (`#1`):

```
 $vouchers->setInputFilter($vouchers->getInputFilter());
 $vouchers->setData($request->getPost());
```

Which don't exist in `Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http()` class.

You should rename your variable `$vouchers` inside first `if` block (`if ($request->isPost())`)

Answer (score 0):

Use  "`addValidator`" method instead of `$vouchers->setInputFilter($vouchers->getInputFilter());`

Ex:

```
$vouchers->addValidator('MimeType', false, 'image/png');
```